# How to create a slow query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

*Elasticsearch v7.7.1*

How can I create a slow query? It is for a test purpose.

For now, I tried to brute force a prime number check:

```
GET _search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "AvgTicketPrice": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless", 
        "source": """
          long num = 524287;
          for (long i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if (num % i === 0) return false;
          return true;
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I discovered Elasticsearch has a limit for the number of statements that can be executed in a loop. The error:

```
{
  "took" : 534,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 21,
    "successful" : 20,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 1,
    "failures" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : ".kibana_1",
        "node" : "uyDLmy1bRT-JFiukjBnzrQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "for (long ",
            "^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : """
          long num = 524287;
          for (long i = 2; i < num; i++)
            if (num % i === 0) return false;
          return true;
        """,
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 40,
            "start" : 40,
            "end" : 50
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "painless_error",
            "reason" : "The maximum number of statements that can be executed in a loop has been reached."
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: @Gibbs Elasticsearch v7.7.1

Comment: Limit is 1000000. Are you sure you tried with 524287

Comment: @Gibbs yes, I tried 524287 and it didn't work. The largest prime number that works is 131071. And it is too small to make the execution time greater than 1s.